# SQL Server 2012 Enforce Password Policy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

If i would like to change the password of my SQL login,
How much time i can't use with the same password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a SQL login with `CHECK_POLICY = ON` the policy adheres to the operating system password policy.

You could find out by going into the local security policy control panel (Start > run > `secpol.msc`) and browsing to "Account policy" and then "Password policy".